# scala- how to subscribe akka leader up event

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka, akka-cluster

I am using akka with play. And I want something to be done only once when a new leader is up

I am going to find something like , in other words, I am looking for something like this.

```
class LeaderUpHook {   
    def onLeaderUp {
        log.log("a new leader is up")   
   } 
}
```

I search the clustering doc , but still don't how to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use the cluster events to figure this out.  I'm basing my code example off of the documentation under the `Subscribe to Cluster Events` section of the docs [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.1/scala/cluster-usage.html).  So in short, you basically create an actor that subscribes into relevant cluster events in order to determine who the leader is and when that leader is up.  That actor could look like this:

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.cluster._

class LeaderUpHandler extends Actor{
  import ClusterEvent._

  val cluster = Cluster(context.system)
  cluster.subscribe(self, classOf[MemberUp])
  cluster.subscribe(self, classOf[LeaderChanged])
  var leader:Option[Address] = None

  def receive = {
    case  state:CurrentClusterState => 
      println(s"Got current state: $state")

    case MemberUp(member) =>
      println(s"member up: $member")
      leader.filter(_ == member.address) foreach{ address => 
        println("leader is now up...")
      }

    case LeaderChanged(address) => 
      println(s"leader changed: $address")
      leader = address
  }
}
```

Then to test this code, you could do the following:

```
val cfg = """
  akka {
      actor {
        provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"               
      }
      remote {
        netty.tcp {
            hostname = "127.0.0.1"
            port = 2552 
        }    
      }
      cluster {
        seed-nodes = [
            "akka.tcp://clustertest@127.0.0.1:2552"
          ]
        auto-down = on
      }     
  }    

"""
val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(cfg).withFallback(ConfigFactory.load)
val system = ActorSystem("clustertest", config)
system.actorOf(Props[LeaderUpHandler])
```

When you run the above code, you should see the leader get determined to be up.  This is an oversimplified example; I'm just trying to show that you can use the cluster events to find what you are looking for.

Comment: Is it necessary to add @volatile to the ```leader```

Comment: Why exactly?  This is an Actor. It processes it's  mailbox one at a time. Concurrent access to the leader var is not an issue. It's private mutable state that only this actor instance has access to.

Comment: The two event may be processed by  different threads, so , I think use volatile can prevent some caching

Comment: Read this documentation and you will see in it that fields in an actor do not need to be marked as volatile. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/general/jmm.html

Comment: seems I had to subscribe CurrentClusterState, or I am not able to receive the leader up when cluster is justing starting